# Chance of UK visit visa approval

Tags: visas, uk

I submitted my visit UK visa application on 23 April, along with 4 months of bank statements, employer's letter (that I have worked for for 2 years), the latest pay slip and my passport with 4 Schengen visas in the past 3 years, as well as my tenancy agreement.

I stated that my monthly income is SGD 5.4k (about 2.7k pounds, supported by payslip), typical spend is $2k and intend to spend $3k on my 13-day trip, which is about 5% of my savings.

Now the issue is that I just realized the bank account (let's call it A) I submitted was opened this January 2018, and I transferred a large sum of money from another bank B (also under my name, and has existed for 11 years). The transaction clearly showed that it is sent from Bank B, under my full name (as seen in passport) to Bank A. Will this be considered as "funds parking"?

The transfers only happened in January and I have been using Bank A as my main spending account since (which is why I forgot I opened it recently and not for a long time). Bank statements for the last 3 months (January, February and April) are maintained with lots of daily spendings and monthly salary.

If only I had submitted the other bank B e-statement, it would have shown clearly they both belong to me, I just transferred from B to A because A has a better interest rate.

What are my odds of approval? I'm a Vietnamese professional working in Singapore for over 2 years with an Employment pass expiring in 2020.

Comment: Wow a good application with such a big blunder, you may have just shot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Yeah I know. But it does show the deposit comes from my name just from different bank :(
If I reapply (this time with both bank accounts) would it be considered on its own merit although my conditions didn't change, just more proof it's my own funds?

Comment: I don't think anyone reading this can accurately calculate your odds of approval. This is called post-application anxiety, You have to wait and see.

Comment: @xyz789 Have you attended your biometric appointment yet? If not, you could cancel this application and resubmit with full bank statements.

Comment: @Traveller `If not, you could cancel this application` - This might not be a good choice. I had the same scenario when I applied for an UK visa i.e. I had sold loads of stocks from my trading account and transferred the money into my bank account, prior to application. And this was all visible in the bank account statement. I didn't provide my trading statements either. And I did get my visa. But it was long long ago and I do know UKBA have become quite a bit stricter.

Comment: @DumbCoder It’s my understanding that up until biometrics are provided, the application is not fully submitted or accepted for processing. UKVI provides information on how to cancel - i.e. withdraw - an application https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa, there are no ‘health warnings’ in the guidance about a withdrawn application prejudicing a decision on a fresh one; the applicant could explain the reason for the withdrawal in the new application.

Comment: @DumbCoder - I got my visa yesterday. It seems they can really tell who the bonafide applicants are.